# In Choregraphe in robot view for Nao the motion widget doesn't show up. Instead the 'inspector' box appears. How can I find the motion widget?

Tags: python, robot, motion, nao-robot, choregraphe

When I try to click on parts of Nao's body in robot view  the motion widget doesn't show up  instead the 'inspector' box appears . How can I find the motion widget window?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The inspector view replaces the motion widget, and brings the same control of the robot's joints. Note that you can also directly move the joints from the 3D view.